# Lazy/inline implement a protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, inline, lazy-evaluation

I want to lazy/inline implement a protocol in Swift. 
So in the point of the implementation I will have access to variables outside the protocol scope ,

Same as implementing a interface in Java without declaring a class:

```
class MyClass:UIView {
  var someComponent:SomeInnerComponent = SomeInnerComponent();
  var count:Int = 0;

  var a = :SomeProtocol { //<----- IS THIS POSSIBLE, IF YES HOW ?
      func a0() {MyClass.count--}
      func a1() {MyClass.count++}
  } 

  someComponenet.delegate = a;
}

protocol SomeProtocol {
  func a0()
  func a1()
}
```

editing----

thanks i look at this solution, and i didn't see how to access a variable of the parent class.
all the examples show an Anonymous class but no one of the examples is accessing the parent variables .

Comment: Note that all of the answers on that other question that discuss closures also addresses your question about "access to variables outside the protocol scope." Closures can capture and modify those variables.

Comment: thanks i look at this solution, and i didn't see how to access a variable of the parent class.
all the examples show an Anonymous class but no one of the examples is accessing the parent variables .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is an inner class (not necessarily an anonymous one), declared in a scope that lets it access the `count` variable of a `MyClass` instance, and that adopts a protocol defined at a different scope. Right now Swift has a few of those pieces, but it doesn't look like you can put them all together in any way that's as concise as what you might be looking for.

You might think about declaring an inner class:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    let someComponent = SomeInnerComponent() // type SomeInnerComponent is inferred
    var count = 0 // type Int is inferred
    class Helper: SomeProtocol {
        func a0() { count-- } // ERROR
        // ...
    }
    init() {
        someComponent.delegate = Helper()
    }
}
```

But that won't work, because `count` is implicitly `self.count`, where `self` is a `Helper` instance, not the `MyView` instance that "owns" the `Helper` instance. And there isn't a way to reference that `MyView` instance (or its properties) from within a `Helper`'s methods, because you could just as well construct a `MyView.Helper()` without having an existing `MyView` instance. Inner classes (or nested types in general) in Swift nest only in lexical scope, not in existential ownership. (Or to put it another way, since you referenced Java: all inner classes in Swift are like static inner classes in Java. There's no non-static inner class.) If that's a feature you'd like, though, [it's probably worth telling Apple you want it](http://bugreport.apple.com).

You could also try declaring `Helper` inside `MyView.init()` -- in Swift you can nest type definitions anywhere, including inside functions or methods of other types. Defined there, it can refer to `MyView`'s properties. However, now the type information for `Helper` is only visible inside of `MyView.init()`, so when you assign it to `someComponent.delegate` (whose type is just `SomeProtocol`), you can't make use of it... this crashes the compiler, even. (That's another [bug to report](http://bugreport.apple.com), but it's hard to say whether the bug is really "compiler crashes on valid usage" or "code is bad, but compiler crashes instead of producing error".)

The closest solution I can come up with looks something like this:

```
class SomeInnerComponent {
    var delegate: SomeProtocol?
}
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func a0()
    func a1()
}
class MyClass  {
    var someComponent = SomeInnerComponent()
    var count = 0
    struct Helper: SomeProtocol {
        var dec: () -> ()
        var inc: () -> ()
        func a0() { dec() }
        func a1() { inc() }
    }
    init() {
        someComponent.delegate = Helper(
            dec: { self.count -= 1 }, // see note below
            inc: { self.count += 1 }
        )
    }
}
```

How it works:

- `Helper` is an inner struct (could be a class, but a struct is simpler)
- It implements the `a0` and `a1` methods, satisfying the requirements of `SomeProtocol`
- The implementations of `a0` and `a1` call through to the closures `dec` and `inc`, which are stored properties (aka instance variables) of the `Helper` struct
- You write (or otherwise specify) these closures when you construct a `Helper` instance (using the default member-wise initializer, `Helper(dec: (Void -> Void), inc: (Void -> Void))`)
- Because you can write the closures when initializing a `Helper`, those closures can capture variables where you're calling the initializer, including the implicit `self` that refers to the `MyClass` instance creating the `Helper`.

You need both `a0`/`a1` and `dec`/`inc` because you need closures (the latter), not methods, for capturing the enclosing state. And even though closures and funcs/methods are in many ways interchangeable, you can't create a method/func implementation by assigning a closure to a method/func name. (It'd be a different story if `SomeProtocol` required closure properties instead of methods, but I'm assuming `SomeProtocol` isn't something under your control.)

Anyway, this is kind of a lot of boilerplate and a layer of abstraction that you might not really need, so it's probably worth looking into other ways to architect your code.

---

Note: my example uses the closure `{ self.count -= 1 }` where you might expect `{ self.count-- }`. The latter doesn't work because that's an expression with a value, so Swift will interpret it as shorthand for the closure's return value. Then it'll complain that you assigned a `() -> Int` closure to a property that expects a `() -> ()` (aka `Void -> Void`) closure. Using `-= 1` instead works around this issue.

Comment: thanks!, nice hack :), this example can serves me, why do i need 'dec','inc' methods. can i use a0, 01 directly ?. is this a limitation in swift ?

Answer (score 3):

I would go for a different approach, I know this a pretty old topic but just in case someone else struggles with this issue:

```
class MyClass:UIView {
  var someComponent:SomeInnerComponent = SomeInnerComponent();
  var count:Int = 0;

  init(){
    // Assign the delegate or do it somewhere else to your preference:
    someComponenet.delegate = ProtocolImplementation(myClass: self);
  }

  private class ProtocolImplementation: SomeProtocol {
      let selfReference: MyClass          

      init(myClass: MyClass){
         selfReference = myClass
      } 

      public func a0(){
         selfReference.count--
      }

      public func a1(){
          selfReference.count++
      }
  }
}

protocol SomeProtocol {
  func a0()
  func a1()
}
```

By following this approach it's also possible to include the same protocol multiple times, lets say your Protocol supports a generic and you want to implement it twice. SomeProtocol< SomeObject > and SomeProtocol< OtherObject > could be both used this way if needed.

Kind regards